# How to know the compilation mode in a genrule

Tags: bazel

I'm using bazel to build my android project. I need to access an environment variable `DEBUG`(self-defined) to determine what value of `BuildConfig.DEBUG` should be, but I can't find any description about this in Bazel's doc. Does Bazel support this? Or what can I do to reach my intent?

Thanks very much for any help!

PS: I'm using the `genrule` rule to generate my `BuildConfig.java`, but the value of `BuildConfig.DEBUG` should be determined by the environment variable `DEBUG`:

```
genrule(
    name = "build-config-genrule",
    outs = [ "BuildConfig.java" ],
    cmd  = "echo 'package com.qzone;" +
           "public class BuildConfig {" +
           "public static final boolean DEBUG = ???;" +
           "}' > $(@)"
)
```

Comment: If you can rename the question to be a bit more specific that could be great since it's very broad and the answer turned out to be very specific.

Comment: OK Ittai, I have updated the question title to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$(COMPILATION_MODE)` Make Variable in the `genrule.cmd`:

> `COMPILATION_MODE`: "fastbuild", "dbg", or "opt".

See [Make Variable substitution](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html#make-var-substitution).

EDIT: Important to mention that COMPILATION_MODE reflects the value of the [`-c` / `--compilation_mode` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--compilation_mode), but there's no way in general to specify values on the command line that you could access in `genrule.cmd`.

Comment: second link appears to be broken